# Making python automatically name a file based on user input

Tags: python

I  have a python script that writes a file that is based on the scalers I apply to other files I call this file APtest.in . To make it easier for the user, I do not want the user to input their own file name rather, python writes the file name. For example, if all mumu, bquark, tau, and ww have a scalar value of .1 the output file name should be alone the lines of DMmodel_010mumu_010tau_010bquark_010ww.in

Thank you in advance!

```
from itertools import zip_longest

play=True
while play:

    mumu=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for muon e.g 0.5 or .5: '))
    bquark=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for bquark e.g 0.5 or .5: '))
    tau=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for tau e.g 0.5 or .5: '))
    ww=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for W e.g 0.5 or .5: ')) 
    MADHAT_statment=('############################################################\n# MADHAT (Model-Agnostic Dark Halo Analysis Tool)\n# Dark Matter Model File: dmtest\n#\n# mass: DM mass in GeV\n# spectrum: photon energy spectrum integrated from 1 to 100 GeV\n###########################################################\n# mass (GeV)   spectrum (1-100 GeV)')
    AP= mumu+bquark+tau+ww

    if AP>1.0:
        Ans=input('Annhilation percentage over 100%\nWould you like to try again?: ')
    if AP<1.0:
        Ans=input('Annhilation percentage is under 100%\nWould you like to try again?: ')
    if AP==1.0:
        break
    while True:
        if Ans =="yes":
            play = True
            break
        elif Ans =="no":
            play=False
            break
        else:
            Ans=input('Incorrect option. Type "yes" to try again or "no" to leave')
  
    Mass=[]
    Muon=[]
    Bquark=[]
    Tau=[]
    WW=[]


    with open ('DMmumu.in') as m:
        MUON=m.readlines()
        for i in range(8,len(MUON)):
            single_line=MUON[i].split('\t')
            Massnum=single_line[0]
            newMuon=float(single_line[1])*mumu
            Mass.append(str(Massnum))
            Muon.append(float(newMuon))

    with open ('DMtautau.in') as t:
        TAU=t.readlines()
        for i in range(8,len(TAU)):
            single_line=TAU[i].split('\t')
            Massnum=single_line[0]
            newTau=float(single_line[1])*tau
            #Mass.append(str(Massnum))
            Tau.append(float(newTau))

    with open ('DMbb.in') as b:
        BQUARK=b.readlines()
        for i in range(8,len(BQUARK)):
            single_line=BQUARK[i].split('\t')
            #Massnum=single_line[0]
            newBquark=float(single_line[1])*bquark
            #Mass.append(str(Massnum))
            Bquark.append(float(newBquark))

    with open ('DMWW.in') as w:
        W_W=w.readlines()
        for i in range(8,len(W_W)):
            single_line=W_W[i].split('\t')
            #Massnum=single_line[0]
            newWW=float(single_line[1])*ww
            #Mass.append(str(Massnum))
            WW.append(float(newWW))

    Spectrum_1=[x+y+z for x,y,z in zip(Muon,Bquark,Tau)]

    NewSpectrum=[w+a for w,a in zip_longest(reversed(Spectrum_1),reversed(WW), fillvalue=0)][::-1]

    with open ('APtest.in','w') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(MADHAT_statment)
        outfile.writelines('\n')

        for i in range(len(NewSpectrum)):
            outfile.writelines(Mass[i])
            outfile.writelines('\t')
            outfile.writelines(str(NewSpectrum[i]))
            outfile.writelines('\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below:

```
file_post = "_%03dmumu_%03dtau_%03dbquark_%03dww.in"%((int)(mumu*100),(int)(tau*100),(int)(bquark*100),(int)(ww*100))

with open ('Dmumu'+file_post) as t:
    etc, etc
```

You will get a filename like:

```
Dmumu_010mumu_010tau_010bquark_010ww.in
```